# Nativescript tab layout approach

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to create an app with NativeScript with the following layout:

1. On top, action bar
2. Content Area in the center (about 80% of screen height)
3. Fixed menu on bottom with 4 buttons

I know that NativeScript provides a TabView, **however this view puts the menu on top for the android version of the app,and doesn't allow to use images as "ItemTitle"**.

So (I think) this leaves me with two options :

- Create 4 different pages and load them when a user taps on the menu
  buttons
- Create one single page and change content according to user
  selection

The first approach is great because I get to separate all xml , js and css files. However navigating between pages can take some time and doesn't give ideal user experience.
The second approach probably will have a better user experience but code will be very hard to maintain.

**Which option should I use? Have any of you dealt with a similar layout?** 
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my app I use the TabView with partial-views in each tab-item. So for each tab-view the content is separated in their own xml,js,css files.

So why not just take this approach and combine it with your option 2?

You could create a main-view with:

- ActionBar
- Centered main-content for partial-views (Stack- og GridLayout)
- SegmentedBar at the bottom for navigation buttons

When the user taps a button on the SegmentedBar, you change the visibility of the corresponding partial-view.

You can use any font-icons as "images" for your title in the `SegmentedBar` also.

UPDATE: Added examples below.

**How to create and reference partial-views**

In your main-view Page-element add the references to each partial view, like here:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" 
xmlns:t1="partial-views/tab1" 
xmlns:t2="partial-views/tab2" 
xmlns:t3="partial-views/tab3">
```

Each partial view consists of  a .xml, .js and perhaps a .css file. I like to place each partial view in separate folders: tab1, tab2, tab3 as an example.

The partial-view xml file would contain only the view-modules, no page-modules. So don't add any Page or ActionBar here. Example of a partial view .xml:

```
<GridLayout loaded="viewLoaded">
  <ListView items="{{ someItemList }}">
   <ListView.itemTemplate>
     ...
    </ListView.itemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

**How to use partial-views**

Now, it's up to you how you want to use the partial-views. Here is an example on how to use them together with a `TabView` component. This is placed in the same page-view where you added the references from the first example.

```
<TabView>
  <TabView.items>

    <TabViewItem title="Tab 1" iconSource="res://tab1">
        <TabViewItem.view>
            <t1:tab1 /> 
        </TabViewItem.view>
    </TabViewItem>

    <TabViewItem title="Tab 2" iconSource="res://tab2" >
        <TabViewItem.view>
            <t2:tab2 />
        </TabViewItem.view>
    </TabViewItem>

    <TabViewItem title="Tab 3" iconSource="res://tab3" >
        <TabViewItem.view>
            <t3:tab3 /> 
        </TabViewItem.view>
    </TabViewItem>

  </TabView.items>
</TabView>
```

Or, you could do it without the TabView, and create something custom:

```
<StackLayout>
  <t1:tab1 id="tab1" visibility="visible" /> 
  <t2:tab2 id="tab2" visibility="collapsed" /> 
  <t3:tab3 id="tab3" visibility="collapsed" /> 
</StackLayout>

<SegmentedBar selectedIndex="0" selectedIndexChanged="segBarSelected">
  <SegmentedBar.items>
    <SegmentedBarItem title="Tab 1" />
    <SegmentedBarItem title="Tab 2" />
    <SegmentedBarItem title="Tab 3" />
  </SegmentedBar.items>
</SegmentedBar>
```

So here would `selectedIndexChanged`control the visibility of each partial view.

Comment: This sounds great! If you have some code snippet to share , it would be awesome! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, I updated my comment and added a few examples. Think this covers the basic pattern for partial-views.