# Can I have the iOS Tab View on top in Native Script?

Tags: html, ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nstabview

I am creating a native script application and I want my tab View to appear on the top for iOS. I know sticking the tabView on the top violates the human interface guideline, but I need to do it this way.

Comment: Not sure the native component allows this on iOS. You'd likely need a custom implementation to do this. A stack layout or gridlayout would work to mimic that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that. Here's how i have done the similar thing -

```
<StackLayout row="0" col="0">
<StackLayout  *ngIf="visibility1" id="mainView" visibility="{{ visibility1 ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}">
    <FirstView></FirstView>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout  *ngIf="visibility2" id="mainView" visibility="{{ visibility2 ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}">
    <SecondView></SecondView>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout  *ngIf="visibility3" id="mainView" visibility="{{ visibility3 ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}">
    <ThirdView></ThirdView>
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

and change the visibility of each component based on the click events.

Comment: Could you please explain if this is using custom buttons or Segmented bar? I dont want to use segmented bar though

Comment: this is juss custom buttons, maintaining layouts through visibilty.

Answer (score 1):

With the new Nativescript 6 there is a new component called "Tabs" that allows you to do this:

Here is how you would do it with Nativescript angular:

```
<Tabs selectedIndex="1" class="fas font-size">
    <!-- Using icon fonts for each TabStripItem -->
    <TabStrip>
        <TabStripItem title="Home"></TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem title="Account"></TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem title="Search"></TabStripItem>
    </TabStrip>

    <TabContentItem>
        <GridLayout>
            <Label text="Home Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <GridLayout>
            <Label text="Account Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <GridLayout>
            <Label text="Search Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </TabContentItem>

</Tabs>
```

[Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=09D1fo&v=2) is a playground project I created.

[Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=z0JIs0&_ga=2.1274865.1911433805.1565631942-1157090987.1562082796)is a playground example with Nativescript typescript using both top and low tabs

[Here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/tabs) you can find the documentation

**important note: this widget is currently on beta**

Comment: They are now out of beta in 6.1. https://www.nativescript.org/blog/tabs-and-bottomnavigation-nativescripts-two-new-components

Answer (score 0):

You can implement all manners of TabView behaviours/layouts using the SegmentedBar. See [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37316966/5748813)